# phpbb3 and facebook logout code

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, phpbb3

That is my page:

```
<?php

define('IN_PHPBB', true);
global $phpbb_root_path;
global $phpEx;
global $user;
global $auth;

$phpEx = 'php';
$phpbb_root_path = '../forum/';

require($phpbb_root_path . "common.php");
$user->session_begin();

$user->session_kill(true);
$user->session_begin();

require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'x',
'secret' => 'x',
'cookie' => true,
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
try {
    echo $facebook->api('/me/permissions', 'delete');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
}
}

unset($_COOKIE['test']);
setcookie('test', null, -1, '/');

header("Location: ../index.php");
```

When I commented out phpbb3 logout code page load fast, but when code is run page load slow?I searched for a method but have not found the solution to my problem. If you can give any advice I would be grateful. The delay is such that, for example, the page opens with a 10 second delay, not immediately. Sorry, for my bad English :(.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! To improve your chances of getting an answer, please refine your question: what is the "phpbb3 logout code"? What do you mean by "fast" and "slow"? What have you tried? Etc. And finally, don't say it is important (or urgent) - improving your question is the best way to get good answers.

Comment: The delay is such that, for example, the page opens with a 10 second delay, not immediately.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't write comment
try this

```
setcookie("test", "", time()-3600,'/');
//-----------------------here time() -value not just -value may help U
```